# Using await Task.Factory.StartNew on a method will return immediately

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, c#-7.1

I'm running the following code (C#7.1 Console App), and I can't really understand why the difference in behavior.

If I await a regular async method call, or a Task.Run - it works as expected (i.e. the app doesn't return immediately). But if I use Task.Factory.StartNew - it will return immediately without the code actually running.

Strangely enough - if I use StartNew but inside the method remove the await, it will not return immediately...

**Problem: This returns immediately:**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo);
}

static async Task DisplayCurrentInfo()
{
    await WaitAndApologize();
    Console.WriteLine($"The current time is {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay:t}");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

i.e. - I won't get to see anything printed out to the console, and the console will already be shut down.

**No problem: this doesn’t return immediately**:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await DisplayCurrentInfo(); // or await Task.Run(DisplayCurrentInfo);
}

static async Task DisplayCurrentInfo()
{
    await WaitAndApologize();
    Console.WriteLine($"The current time is {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay:t}");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

**Strange: this also doesn't return immediately:**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo); 
}

static async Task DisplayCurrentInfo()
{
    WaitAndApologize();
    Console.WriteLine($"The current time is {DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay:t}");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

WaitAndApologize:

```
static async Task WaitAndApologize()
{
    // Task.Delay is a placeholder for actual work.  
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    // Task.Delay delays the following line by two seconds.  
    Console.WriteLine("\nSorry for the delay. . . .\n");
}
```

Comment: By "return immediately" you mean "immediately returns a task that hasn't completed yet", right? If so then that is expected and by design. If that wasn't what you meant, please clarify. Do you get a completed task in return?

Comment: And don't wrap a task inside a task, you need double awaits. You're spawning a task A using `Task.Run`, the purpose of this task is to create another task, B, and you're awaiting A, but not B. Unless you know how to do this correctly, don't use that call syntax, simply do what works.

Comment: A quick fix that will probably leave you with more questions if you didn't understand my second comment is to just use double awaits: `await await Task.Factory....`, but a *better* fix is to go with just `await DisplayCurrentInfo();`.

Comment: Once you're starting down the route of writing `async` code, any *manual* construction of `Task`s (via `Run` or `StartNew`) is probably questionable. You `async` methods already create `Task`s - why do you want even more of them?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen interesting, so await await is legal syntax i followed what you were saying i think. Could you post what you said with more details and examples, i thought it was quite helpful in understanding what is happening.Thx, yes i know i didn't ask the question, but liked your explanation.

Comment: If you wrap enough tasks inside each other you can write all the awaits you want, `await X` gives a new expression, if this expression is something that has an awaiter, you can await that as well, and so on ad infinitum. Taskception.

Comment: Where did you see that it's recommended to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use `Task.Factory.StartNew(MethodThatReturnsTask)` you get back a `Task<Task<T>>` or `Task<Task>` depending on whether the method is returning a generic task or not.

The end result is that you have 2 tasks:

1. `Task.Factory.StartNew` spawns a task that calls `MethodThatReturnsTask`, let's call this task "Task A"
2. `MethodThatReturnsTask` in your case returns a `Task`, let's call this "Task B", this means that an overload of `StartNew` that handles this is used and the end result is that you get back a Task A that wraps Task B.

To "correctly" await these tasks needs 2 awaits, not 1. Your single await simply awaits Task A, which means that when it returns, Task B is still executing pending completion.

To naively answer your question, use 2 awaits:

```
await await Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo);
```

However, it is questionable why you need to spawn a task just to kick off another async method. Instead you're much better off using the second syntax, where you simply await the method:

```
await DisplayCurrentInfo();
```

---

**Opinion follows**: In general, once you've started writing async code, using `Task.Factory.StartNew` or any of its sibling methods should be reserved for when you need to spawn a *thread* (or something similar) to call something that isn't async in parallel with something else. If you're not requiring this particular pattern, it's best to not use it.

Comment: Instead of await await, I would do a Unwrap of the first task. But I agree with your overall conclusion, don't user StartNew if it's not needed.

Comment: Ah... I understand now. Though you didn't answer the "strange" case, but VibeeshanRC explained it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo);` you are using the signature:

```
public Task<TResult> StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
```

Now since you are passing a method with the signature `Task DisplayCurrentInfo()` then the `TResult` type is `Task`.

In other words you are returning a `Task<Task>` from `Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo)` and you are then awaiting the outer task which returns `Task` - and you're not awaiting that. Hence it completes immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo);
```

The first example does return imediatly, because you are creating a new Task and awaiting it, which will call another task but that is not waited. Think about a **psudo code** like below inorder to keep awaited.

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew( await DisplayCurrentInfo); //Imaginary code to understand
```

In the third example `WaitAndApologize` is not **awaited**, but its getting blocked by thread sleep (Full Thread is blocked).

With only the help of code we can't say that the Task factory has created a new thread or just running on the existing thread. 
If its running in the same thread, the whole thread is getting blocked, so you are getting a feeling that the code is awaiting at `await Task.Factory.StartNew(DisplayCurrentInfo);` , but atually its not happening.

If its running on a differnet thread, you will not get the same result as above.

Comment: If you were to rewrite the second piece of code to actually compile you would need to write an async lambda expression or anonymous method, in which case you now have 3 tasks and you're still left with the double await on the outside.

Comment: plus one and Thanks for the explanation about the strange case. I get it now.